# Do Azure Pipelines custom tasks support json object as input?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

If so, a simple example of a `task.json` that has a json object as input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible. You can't attach a file to task definition in YAML or classic pipeline. What you can do is to put it somewhere over Internet (Like Azure Blob Storage) and get it via curl.